# Amplifying noise floor

Tags: noise, noisefloor

Let's say you have -120Db noise floor on an amplifier circuit. You feed this noise into an ideal noiseless amplifier with an Av=25. What is the new noise floor? Proper equation?

Comment: -120dB what?  A dB is a relative measure; to make it absolute you need to append some reference to it, such as dBV (decibels relative to a volt), dBm (decibels relative to a milliwatt, please don't ask why RF guys like that instead of dBW), etc.  Is this homework?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Can you show some work?

Comment: Sorry, no homework sir. Dbvrms - let's figure AF bandwidth. No signal either.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the noise floor you are referring to is in dBV. 
The new noise floor then would be..

\$ -120 + 20log_{10}(25)=-92dB\$